# How to remove a set of IAtmoicLong counter from Hazzle cast memory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, counter

I am creating multiple IAtomicLong based counter dynamically in Hazzle cast for a requirement. 
**I would like to know if I am creating multiple IAtomicLong based counter will it create any memory related issues like OOM ?**

**If so what is the option I will have in removing the counters from hazzle cast memory at particular interval of time.?**
I checked for any TTL(Time to live) setting in IAtomicLong and was not able to find one.

Regards
Arun

Answer (score 0):

Would an IMap work for your situation?
Keys for an IMap have a TTL
And for using the Value as a counter, you can use an [EntryProcessor](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html-single/index.html#creating-an-entry-processor) to increment and decrement your counter